# Prevent service collisions after aapt --rename-manifest-package

Tags: android, android-service, aapt

I'm creating a white-labeled application.  I run the project through aapt with the --rename-manifest-package option.

This allows me write
com.foobar

And release

*com.foobar.demo* and *com.foobar.extended* versions to be installed on the same device.

However, even though the services are set via both permission android:permission="@string/permission_name" (which changes per install) and android:exported="false" each app wants to call the other apps services!

I.e. when I start *com.foobar.extended* I get a security exception about it not having permission for *com.foobar.demo*'s service!

It appears that -rename-manifest-package doesn't change the service intent filters, so they remain *com.foobar.services.X* meaning that one apps services have higher priority for processing the intents.

How can I prevent this issue? (Maybe a startLocalService() which doesn't send the intents outside the application...)

Thanks,

John

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided a copy of your manifest file, but I would guess that you have used absolute names there, whereas you should have been using relative names.

Instead of

```
<service android:name="com.foobar.demo.service" />
```

you should use

```
<service android:name=".service" />
```

(Notice that the name starts with a period).

Comment: I am using relative service names in the AndroidManifest.xml file.  However when I start the service I use and Intent with a String action.  I.e. "com.foobar.services.MyService".

Comment: -rename-manifest-package will not know to change the internal string you use to start a service.  The reason for using a relative name in the manifest is that you can then build the name up at runtime using `context.packageName() + ".service"`